# Prophet Error: tick_w = max(df_none['horizon'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')) / 10

Tags: python, anaconda, nonetype, prophet

I am using Prophet version 1.4 with Anaconda on a 64 bit machine and get the following error:

```
tick_w = max(df_none['horizon'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')) / 10.
```

The type of error is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Based on my research, this was resolved in an older version. I appreciate any suggestion you have.

Tried fbprophet and could not install it, as it might have been discontinued - it could not resolve the environment after a long time. Also, this problem is intermittent and I guess something in data can trigger it, but I do not know what.

I am guessing that may be I should use an older version

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with a version but rather a selection of the cost  function causing this. This can be corrected by improving data preprocessing to avoid the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).